# React native break loop on new state or unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, for-loop, async-await

I have a React component where I want to create a loop when it's mounted and stop the loop when it's unmounted or when `autoGathering` state changes. Inside the loop, there is an async function so each itineration should wait for the function to finish before moving to the next one. Everything should stop when `Stop` button is tapped.

My current and broken code:

```
const AutoGather = ({autoGathering, stopAutoGather}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (autoGathering) {
                processAutoGather(i, autoGathering).then(() => {
                    console.log('other ', i)
                })
            } else {
                console.log('stopping')
                break
            }
        }
    }, [])


    // Some async function here, Database operation and probably a setTimeout
    const processAutoGather = async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (autoGathering) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('resolving')
                    return resolve(true)
                }, 1000)
            } else {
                console.log('rejecting')
                return reject(false)
            }
        })
        
    }

    return (
        <Layout style={{flex:1}}>
            <Layout style={{flex:1}}>
                <Layout style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <Button style={{borderRadius:20, minWidth:125}} onPress={()=> stopAutoGather()} status='danger' size='small'>Stop Auto Gather</Button>
                </Layout>
            </Layout>
        </Layout>
    )
}

AutoGather.propTypes = {
    autoGathering: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    materialToGather: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    stopAutoGather: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default AutoGather
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to await the gathering to complete before launching the next one. Also, you need to clean dependencies of `useEffect`:

```js
// Create a promise and save the `resolve` for using outside it
const AutoGather = ({autoGathering, stopAutoGather}) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      let stopTheCount = false;
      (async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5 && !stopTheCount; i++) {
          await processAutoGather(i);
          console.log('other ', i);
        }
      })();

      // Stop the count!
      return () => { stopTheCount = true };
    }, []);

    // Some async function here, Database operation and probably a setTimeout
    const processAutoGather = async (counter) => {
        return autoGathering
          ? new Promise( (resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  if(autoGathering) {
                    console.log('resolving')
                    return resolve(true)
                  }
                }, 1000)
            })
          : Promise.resolve()
    }

    return (...)
}
```

Comment: I've tried something similar the problem is that the loop won't stop when unmounting. While I'm using 5 as an example it really should run until stopped. The for loop in the example was just one of the last things I tried.

Comment: Added a Promise abort mechanism. Not tested.

Comment: `I've tried something similar the problem is that the loop won't stop when unmounting` No, it doesn't, but the called function will do nothing if `autoGathering` is false.

Comment: This is a bit tricky and may have some bugs. You probably preffer something like `simple-abortable-promise` with `npm install simple-abortable-promise`. More at [the blog post](https://zzdjk6.medium.com/a-simple-implementation-of-abortable-promise-using-abortcontroller-with-typescript-2c163ee050e8) and [the repo](https://github.com/zzdjk6/simple-abortable-promise).

Comment: Moved the aborting mechanism outside the React component.

Comment: I will take a look, the problem is that you could start, stop, start... a few times and all the loops and db ops will actually continue to run in background until the for loop ends. `autoGathering` does not seem to update and stop future calls.

Comment: Even with your latest code it still keeps going until the loop is finished. I've tried everything, loops, recursive functions, while loops. Nothing seems to stop it.

Comment: Edited with different approach: Stop the count!

Comment: If you want to restart the count also on some state or prop change, add them to the array at the end of `useEffect` (which is empty currently).